# Parts of Visual C++ IDE GUI stops refreshing

Tags: visual-c++

I'm having a weird bug on one of my computers with Visual C++. For some reason the screen will stop refreshing where my source code is. I can force a single refresh if I minimize and maximize Visual C++.

For example if I try to type something or use the scroll bar, it will not show any changes until I minimize and maximize. If I type something the changes have been made however. I can save and those changes will remain.

Oddly auto-complete still works as intended. If I type myClass.get_ it will bring up the auto-complete window.

It seems to occur randomly. It can happen if I leave the program up for a bit while doing other things or when I first start up the program. A fresh reboot nearly always fixes at that moment but what ever the cause is will occur after time. One thing that nearly always causes the program to stop working is if I start a video game.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: The VS version is important.  But the solution is about the same, you need to get your machine stable again.  Focus on video driver and DirectX install (relevant to VS2010).  Some odds for an add-on causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is VS2010 - I think it does new-fangled GUI things with WPF and notably relies on hardware acceleration and write combining quite a lot more than before.

I had display issues in a virtual box gues installation (with multiple-monitor support in the guest enabled). I worked around it by lowering / disabling the hardware acceleration settings for the (virtual) graphics adaptor.

- right click desktop
- screen resolution
- advanced/performance
- use the slider to adjust acceleration level

Changing this setting apparently required a reboot on my system when I did it.